# Duplicate and missing log entries with FluentBit and ES

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, microservices, fluent-bit

We're using `FluentBit` to ship microservice logs into `ES` and recently found an issue on one of the environments: some log entries are duplicated (up to several hundred times) while other entries are missing in `ES/Kibana` but can be found in the microservice's container (`kubectl logs my-pod -c my-service`).
Each duplicate log entry has a unique `_id` and `_fluentBitTimestamp` so it really looks like the problem is on FluentBit's side.

FluentBit version is 1.5.6, the configuration is:

```
[SERVICE]
    Flush        1
    Daemon       Off
    Log_Level    info
    Log_File     /fluent-bit/log/fluent-bit.log
    Parsers_File /fluent-bit/etc/parsers.conf
    Parsers_File /fluent-bit/etc/parsers_java.conf

[INPUT]
    Name              tail
    Path              /home/xng/log/*.log
    Exclude_Path      /home/xng/log/*.zip
    Parser            json
    Buffer_Max_Size   128k

[FILTER]
    Name record_modifier
    Match *
    Record hostname ${HOSTNAME}

[OUTPUT]
    Name  es
    Match *
    Host es-logging-service
    Port 9210
    Type flink-logs
    Logstash_Format On
    Logstash_Prefix test-env-logstash
    Time_Key _fluentBitTimestamp
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We had same problem
Can you try in your configuration
**Write_operation upsert**
So if log has duplicate _id it will update instead of create
Please note, Id_Key or Generate_ID is required in update, and upsert scenario.

https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/elasticsearch#write_operation

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Continuing rasvi's answer, I was able to fix this by configuring the **Generate_ID On** option output on the configuration file. As describe on [this doc](https://docs.fluentbit.io/manual/pipeline/outputs/elasticsearch#write_operation)
In your case:

```
[OUTPUT]
    Name  es
    Match *
    Host es-logging-service
    Port 9210
    Type flink-logs
    Logstash_Format On
    Logstash_Prefix test-env-logstash
    Time_Key _fluentBitTimestamp
    Generate_ID On
```